# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Go Sample Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html) to setup elastic beanstalk using CloudFormation and had a question on the following section

```
    SourceBundle:
       S3Bucket: !Sub "elasticbeanstalk-samples-${AWS::Region}"
       S3Key: php-newsample-app.zip
```

I was wondering if anyone can tell me the proper S3Key for the Go sample app?
I have tried a few options but nothing is working

Thanks in advance
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s3key is synonymous with the path where you want to deploy the app. I recommend you to read Go blog post about AWS elastic beanstalk the link below

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-tutorial.html